# Screen shuts down when trying to install or try ubuntu?

Tags: installation, nvidia, intel-graphics, lenovo

I bought Lenovo Y510P and I want to use Ubuntu. When I try install or try Ubuntu the screen shuts down and nothing appears. When I selected to try Ubuntu. I hear the sound of Ubuntu start yet, the screen still turned off. I now installed Ubuntu on the hard driver, the screen still turns off when I start Ubuntu. However, I tired to make the laptop sleep by clicking fn+f1 then when I press any key to wake it up the screen turns on ! Does anyone have an explanation, if so how to fix it ?

Note: I have two video cards Nvidia GForce 750M 2GB and Intell video card.

Answer (score 0):

I have the y410p, and had a similar problem. I managed to figure out that the screen brightness is defaulting to all the way down every time I reboot. I hold down <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> arrow key (yours may be different) and it comes back. I haven't figured out how to fix this yet...more pressing concerns unfortunately.  Whine and popping in the speakers on battery power, etc.